# Define name using Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to make rule for domain name using Regex. The Name should be between 2 and 63 characters long can contain letters `[a-zA-Z]`, numbers `[0-9]` and `-` sign. It can't start or finish with a `-` and it can't have more than 2 `-` in a row. Also double `-` is forbidden on positions 3 and 4. Please help I am stuck at least one of the conditions escapes me.

Comment: You're almost there... look at the regexes you posted, so close. Post your attempts.

Comment: Please add a few examples of valid and invalid names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Name should be between 2 and 63 characters long

```
^.{2,63}$
```

> can contain letters [a-zA-Z], numbers[0-9] and '-'sign.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,63}$
```

> It can't start or finish with a '-'

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

> and it can't have more than 2 '-' in a row.

```
^(?!.*---)[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

> Also double '-' is forbidden on positions 3 and 4.

```
^(?!.*---)(?!..--)(?!...--)[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

---

`(?!)` are *negative zero-width lookahead assertions* (negative [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), for short). They make sure that a certain condition is not true in the string that lies ahead of a certain position.

Comment: `{2,61}` should be `{0,61}`